# Is there a proof of this statement about deductions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

Is there a proof of the following statement: you cannot prove with natural deduction theorems that are unprovable in a Hilbert-style proof system? The logic in discussion is either propositional logic or FOL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to follow a "typical" proof of "equivalence" between *Natural Deduction* and *Hilbert-style*.

See :

> Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521068428) (2001), page 41-on.

An alternative approach is through *soundness* and *completeness*.

Both proof systems are *sound* and *complete* regarding *valid* formulae; thus, a formula unprovable in *ND*, being **not** valid, in not provable in *H-s*, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but the alternative approach is quite ingenious, such a shame I haven't thought of it myself.

Comment: @user132181 - This is the "key" for all different *prooof systems*; they works in a lot of different ways but we want that all agree exactly on the "class" of *valid* formulae (or *tautology* for prop logic).

Comment: Yeah, model theory here serves as a "bridge", so to speak. Very nice.